# Copy + Paste Multiple Events in FullCalendar using React + Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fullcalendar, copy-paste

I am working on a scheduling application using FullCalendar in React, and I'd like to enable the ability to copy and paste event blocks within the calendar using keyboard shortcuts (Ctrl + C, Ctrl + V). The goal is to provide users with an intuitive way to duplicate events easily.

I have implemented the FullCalendar component with event handling functionalities such as dragging, dropping, and event deletion. The calendar displays events and allows users to interact with them using the UI controls provided.

I want to enhance the user experience by allowing them to copy an existing event block by pressing Ctrl + C and paste it at a specific time slot by pressing Ctrl + V within the calendar.

```
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin, {
  Draggable,
  DropArg,
} from "@fullcalendar/interaction";
import allLocales from "@fullcalendar/core/locales-all";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { EventImpl } from "@fullcalendar/core/internal";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {
  faPlus,
  faTrash,
  faXmark,
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

interface MyEvent {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  startTime: string;
  endTime: string;
  color: string;
}

function App() {
  const [events, setEvents] = useState<MyEvent[]>([]);
  const [newEvent, setNewEvent] = useState<MyEvent>();
  const [anyArea, setAnyArea] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [formVisibility, setFormVisibility] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeyPress = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
      if (event.key === "Escape") {
        setFormVisibility(false);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const containerEl = document.querySelector("#bolgeler") as HTMLElement;

    const draggable = new Draggable(containerEl, {
      itemSelector: ".bolge",
      eventData: (eventEl) => {
        const event: MyEvent = {
          id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000).toString(),
          title: eventEl.innerText,
          color: window.getComputedStyle(eventEl).backgroundColor,
          startTime: "",
          endTime: "",
        };

        setNewEvent(event);
        return event;
      },
    });

    console.log(events); //debugging
    return () => {
      draggable.destroy();
    };
  }, [events]);

  const handleEventDrop = (info: DropArg) => {
    if (newEvent) {
      const eventWithDate: MyEvent = {
        ...newEvent,
        startTime: info.dateStr,
      };
      setEvents((prevEvents) => [...prevEvents, eventWithDate]);
      setNewEvent(undefined);
    }
  };

  const handleEventRemove = (info: EventImpl) => {
    info.remove();
    setEvents((prevEvents) =>
      prevEvents.filter((event) => event.id !== info.id)
    );
  };

  const handleOpenForm = () => {
    const popupButton = document.getElementById("bolgeEkle");
    const popupForm = document.getElementById("popupform");

    if (popupButton && popupForm) {
      popupButton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
        setFormVisibility(true);
      });

      window.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        if (event.target !== popupButton) {
          setFormVisibility(false);
        }
      });

      popupForm.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
      });
    }
  };
  const handleAddNewRegion = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const bolgelerDiv = document.getElementById("bolgeler");

    if (bolgelerDiv) {
      setAnyArea(true);
      const yeniBolge = document.createElement("div");

      const yeniBolgeIsim = document.getElementById(
        "bolgeAdi"
      ) as HTMLInputElement;

      const yeniBolgeRenk = document.getElementById(
        "bolgeRenk"
      ) as HTMLInputElement;

      yeniBolge.textContent = yeniBolgeIsim.value;
      yeniBolge.style.backgroundColor = yeniBolgeRenk.value;

      yeniBolge.classList.add("bolge");
      bolgelerDiv.appendChild(yeniBolge);

      yeniBolgeIsim.value = "";
      yeniBolgeRenk.value = "";

      setFormVisibility(false);
    } else {
      setAnyArea(false);
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div id="takvim">
        <FullCalendar
          eventContent={(eventInfo) => {
            return (
              <div className="event-wrapper">
                <div className="event-details">
                  <div>{eventInfo.timeText}</div>
                  <div>{eventInfo.event.title}</div>
                </div>

                <div>
                  <button
                    id="event-delete-button"
                    onClick={() => {
                      if (
                        window.confirm(
                          `Şeçili bölgeyi silmek istediğinizden emin misiniz?`
                        )
                      ) {
                        handleEventRemove(eventInfo.event);
                      }
                    }}
                  >
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} />
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          }}
          headerToolbar={{
            start: "title",
            end: "",
          }}
          windowResizeDelay={100}
          handleWindowResize={true}
          plugins={[timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
          slotLabelFormat={{
            hour: "2-digit",
            minute: "2-digit",
          }}
          slotDuration={"00:15:00"}
          selectable={true}
          editable={true}
          droppable={true}
          allDaySlot={false}
          forceEventDuration={true}
          dayHeaderFormat={{
            weekday: "long",
          }}
          locales={allLocales}
          locale={"tr"}
          events={{ events }}
          drop={(info) => handleEventDrop(info)}
        />
      </div>

      <div id="bolgeler">
        <div id="bolge-baslik">
          <strong>Bölgeler</strong>

          <button id="bolgeEkle" onClick={handleOpenForm}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} />
          </button>
        </div>

        {anyArea || (
          <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}> Kayıtlı Bölge Bulunmamaktadır.</p>
        )}
      </div>

      <form
        id="popupform"
        className="popup-form"
        style={{ display: formVisibility ? "block" : "none" }}
        onSubmit={handleAddNewRegion}
      >
        <h2>Yeni Bölge Ekle</h2>
        <label htmlFor="bolgeAdi">Bölge Adı: </label>
        <input type="text" id="bolgeAdi" name="bolgeAdi" required />
        <label htmlFor="bolgeRenk">Bölge Rengi: </label>
        <input type="color" id="bolgeRenk" name="bolgeRenk" />
        <input type="submit" value="Ekle" />

        <button
          type="button"
          className="close-button"
          onClick={() => alert("asasd")}
        >
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faXmark} />
        </button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

[image: It should be something like this. It can be copied any time user wants]